# Unknown server tag 'uComponents:RenderTemplate'

Tags: umbraco

Unknown server tag 'uComponents:RenderTemplate'.
Hi, just upgraded to 4.7.1 from 4.9.1 and the back office seems to be working ok however when I wish to view my web site I keep getting "Unknown server tag 'uComponents:RenderTemplate'"  error from templates tags.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that's in the uComponents.Controls assembly. Make sure you have uComponents.Controls.dll in your bin folder. Also, I think that you need uComponents 5 with 4.9.1 (but uComponents 4 with 4.7.1). see: http://ucomponents.codeplex.com/

You should get a new version of uComponents.